# How do you insert a sparkline in excel without using

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sparklines

How can I create a Sparkline in Excel without going into the "insert" tab?

I'm looking for a formula or formula-like input I can write into a cell to generate the Sparkline.

Idealy something like:

[image]

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no formula, however you can just create one and then fill it down and you will have multiple spark lines. The data sources are dynamic and will reference each row.

Also, if you format your data as a table, each time you add a new row of data, the sparkline will automatically create for the new row.

[image: Table Example]

Answer (score 1):

I found [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_sparklines2.html) solved my problem. It's a Python library where you can write:

```
worksheet1.add_sparkline('A2', {'range': 'Sheet2!A1:J1'})
```

I also found it's other features very convenient. And it's well documented.